# How to solve Error initializing SDK: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initSdk on channel Channel_name)

Tags: flutter

How to solve Error initializing SDK: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initSdk on channel Channel_name). The code shows no error, but I get this error when I run my app. I am connecting an SDK to my app.

Function in initialize SDK (kotlin file)

```
   private fun initSdk(result: Result) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.post {
            mSys = mDriverManager.getBaseSysDevice()
            mSys?.let { sys ->
                val status = sys.sdkInit()
                if (status != SdkResult.SDK_OK) {
                    print('c')
                    sys.sysPowerOn()
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000)
                    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                val finalStatus = sys.sdkInit()
                if (finalStatus != SdkResult.SDK_OK) {
                    result.error("INIT_SDK_FAILED", "SDK initialization failed", null)
                } else {
                    result.success(null)
                }
            } ?: result.error("INIT_SDK_FAILED", "BaseSysDevice not available", null)
        }
    }
```

Initialize SDK (Dart file)

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PosSdk {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('Channel_name');

  static Future<void> initSdk() async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('initSdk');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Missing');
      print("Failed to initialize SDK: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
}
```

Calling Function (main.dart)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call initSdk method here
    initSdk();
  }

  Future<void> initSdk() async {
    try {
      await PosSdk.initSdk();
      print('SDK initialized successfully.');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing SDK: $e');
    }
```

How to solve Error initializing SDK: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initSdk on channel Channel_name)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for changes on the native side, you need to stop the project and re-run it to enable normal communication. However, the kotlin file you provided is incomplete. I am not sure if there is an error in kotlin.